# Screen message "Must be connected to a terminal" when using option -D -R SessionName

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi2, gnu-screen, autostart

I have script in bash which check for mp4 file and if it find more than one it start playing them one by one.

Script working from command line when i log in by ssh.

But when i reboot rpi, it will not start with autostart in rc.local saying

"Must be connected to a terminal"

This is part of the script

```
    if [ "$count_dir_video" -gt "1"  ] ;then
 53 
 54                 # make background black to hide wallpaper between videos
 55                 DISPLAY=:0 screen -dmS "black_background" feh -FxYqZ /opt/scripts/black_background.jpg
 56                 echo "przed sleep"
 57                 #screen -dmS "$1" sleep 5
 58                 echo "po sleep"
 59 
 60                         while :
 61                         do
 62                                 for entry in $root_dir_video
 63                                 do
 64 
 65                                 # multiple files
 66                                 echo "przed omx"
 67                                 screen -D -R "$1" omxplayer -o hdmi -p -b --no-osd --vol 100 "$entry" >> /var/log/sds.log
 68                                 echo "po omx"
 69                                 done
 70                         done
 71                 else
 72 
 73                         # single file
 74 
 75                         screen -dmS "$1" omxplayer -o hdmi -p -b --loop --no-osd --vol 100 "$root_dir_video"
 76                 fi
```

The problem is in line 67 and i cannot make it work.

I tried other parameter screen combination but always the same.

The idea is that it will start every entry in once named screen session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man screen

```
   -D -R   Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is run‐
           ning, then reattach. If necessary detach  and  logout  remotely
           first.   If  it  was not running create it and notify the user.
           This is the author's favorite.
```

Use lowercase `-d` with `-m`.

Comment: I tried that but with this combination it will create multiple sessions named like "$1" parameter, and as i said i want one session which will be reattached during the loop.

Comment: Sry but i dont understand how to put commands in one line can you specify it a bit more clearer ?